# How to use a list of classes as a function parameter?

Tags: python, list, class

I am learning python(3) after using C# for several years. Therefore i am coding some home project in python but i encountered some issue i cant seem to figuere out how to do in python.

Lets say i have a simple class like this:

```
class SomeItem:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        # Instance Variable
        self.var1= var1
        self.var2= var2
        self.var3 = var3
```

At some point in my code i am using this class to put a bunch of them in a list;

```
list_of_SomeItems = []
list_of_SomeItems.append(SomeItem("apple","banana", "pear"))
list_of_SomeItems.append(SomeItem("fruit","candy", "drinks"))
# so on and so forth
return list_of_SomeItems
```

But now comes the part i cant seem to figure out
At a certain point i want to make a function that takes a list of these `SomeItems` and do somtehing with is.

```
def name_of_function(interval=1.0, someItemsList):
    for item in someItemsList:
        print(item.var1)
```

but obvious it wouldn't know at this point that `item` has a var1 as i havnt told the function that the list must be of `SomeItem` objects.

What is the proper way to declare the list in my function and associate that parameter with a class?

**EDIT**
fixed;
as @chepner and @Perfect mentioned the mistake was the optional parameter was put first (plain syntax error); after fixing that error; it worked as desired.

Comment: Where is `csvList` defined?

Comment: You never created any instance of `SomeItem`. This code should produce a `TypeError`, because `list.append` doesn't take multiple arguments.

Comment: `list_of_SomeItems.append(SomeItem("apple", "banana", "pear"))`, etc.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed; you don't *have* to tell the function that `item` has a particularly type. if `item.var1` can succeed, it will.

Comment: err.. You keep changing the code in the question. Have you actually tried running any of this? Do you get an error traceback?

Comment: In the line of definition `def name_of_function(interval=1.0, someItemsList):`, keyword argument should follow the positional arguments. So this like `def name_of_function(someItemsList, interval=1.0`

Comment: @quamrana yea i hit the post i bit to fast; but within the first 5 minutes after posting the question i fixed some typing mistakes; as its simplified parts of a bigger code i haven't been copy-pasting everything.
It should all be oke now, but as posted; obvious the function deceleration is faulty but that is the point of the question

Comment: @Perfect ooh damnit; turns out the only isse was that the optional parameter was first and nor the list; beside that python understand as you mentioned. wouw.. this is so different form what i was used to with c#
thanx

Comment: If you *must* have some sort of typing, you can *annotate* using `def func(items: List[SomeItem], interval: float = 1.0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code will work as is after you fix the syntax errors.

Python is dynamically typed, you can just try `foo.bar`, and it will succeed if `foo` has the `bar` attribute, and if it doesn't it will just raise an `AttributeError` which you can catch with `except` and move on.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on python 3.5 and above, you can use the typing module to pass data type of the parameters. You can do this the following way:

```
from typing import List

class Item:
    def __init__(self, var1: str, var2: str, var3: str):
        self.var1: str = var1
        self.var2: str = var2
        self.var3: str = var3

itemlist = [Item("apple","banana", "pear"),Item("fruit","candy", "drinks")]
```

## Function returns var1 from list of Item class instances

```
def get_var_one(items: List[Item])-> List[str]:
    return [elem.var1 for elem in items]
```

You can use the library **`mypy`** to perform static type check on your code.

Answer (score 1):

> it wouldn't know at this point that item has a `var1` as I haven't told the function that the list must be of `SomeItem` objects.

That's likely a design problem. When you create a list of things, they should generally have something in common -- that's why they're on the same list. Why would you put items on the list that don't have a `var1` attribute, if you're later going to try to access that attribute?

It is possible to create heterogeneous lists and use conditional code and exception handling, but it often reflects confusion in the design.

Comment: I assumed that python couldn't know; but it seems python does;
the reason for my assumption was that i used c# for several years now, and there you need to actually declare it specifically 'list<SomeItem> someItemsList'
seems my assumption of python was completely wrong